# Showing Nested JSON Data in Separate Rows - Angular

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular

I want to show this data in seperate rows cause at the moment they are getting all in 1 row only. I want to show the 'FROM' from the JSON Data

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="from">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> From </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <tr>{{element.computationrates[0].ratebands[0].from}}</tr>
        <tr>{{element.computationrates[0].ratebands[1].from}}</tr>
        <tr>{{element.computationrates[0].ratebands[2].from}}</tr>
        <tr>{{element.computationrates[0].ratebands[3].from}}</tr>
      </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

Can someone show me how to edit this code to make them appear in different rows

**JSON Data**

```
        [
     {
  "yearlyincentive": {
      "incentive": {
          "number": "0",
          "description": "null"
      },
      "year": "2016"
  },
  "computationrates": {
          "0": {
              "computation": "0",
              "ratetype": "0",
              "ratebands": [
                  {
                      "from": "0",
                      "to": "8,000",
                      "percent": "15%",
                      "subtract": "100" 
                  },
                  {
                      "from": "8,000",
                      "to": "15,000",
                      "percent": "20%",
                      "subtract": "250" 
                  },
                  {
                      "from": "15,000",
                      "to": "25,000",
                      "percent": "25%",
                      "subtract": "500" 
                  },
                  {
                      "from": "25,000",
                      "to": "50,000",
                      "percent": "35%",
                      "subtract": "1000" 
                  }
              ]
          }
  }
 }
 ]
```

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackblitz.com/angular/kbalobvxxek?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: Yes but these are for the same column.. i need to show the 0,1,2,3 all in different rows and when i try to do ratebands.from only nothing turns up

Comment: Can you add your data you want to display?

Comment: I need to show all the 'FROM' in separate rows.. I Updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Cause as they are they show in one row only

Comment: The json  you provided  is not valid

Comment: I Edited the question

Comment: ok. I will check it

Comment: Do you want to achieve sth like this?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psbjhd

Comment: Yes, but in separate rows.. not in the same row

Comment: This in separate rows, then you mean in separate columns not rows

Comment: In separate rows.. by having a line under each value.. like a normal table

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No. It has to do with the nested structure of your json.  It does not play well with mat-table

Comment: I managed to get this using css but it is a bit ugly and you need to adjust it to be responsive. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psbjhd-s3psui Regards

Comment: isnt there another way using html?